# Create expression tree from prefix regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, prefix

I'm given a regular expression in prefix notation like the one below:

```
(r* (r. r| a ( r. b b) (r. c (r* c))) a))
```

Where:

```
c (for any char c) means "regex accepting the single-character string c"
r. means "regex accepting the empty string"
r/ means "regex accepting nothing"
(r| r1 r2 ...) means "r1 union r2 union ..."
(r. r1 r2 ...) means "r1 concat r2 union ..."
(r* r1) means "r1*"
```

How would I go about parsing this into an expression tree given the above regex as input? It can't just be split at whitespace because there's whitespace within some of the terms, so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: This sounds like homework. If so, what are the constraints? Are you supposed to use regexps to parse this, or write a parser? If the latter, can you use libraries like `pyparsing`, or do you have to do everything from scratch with nothing but the stdlib?

Comment: @abarnert it is homework. We're supposed to write a parser, but are allowed to use a library like pyparsing if we prefer. I just have no experience with that library and have found no examples of it being used for prefix (Polish) notation.

Comment: Also, `(r. r1 r2)` looks ambiguous. Is there a precedence to the rules (try to apply the rules greedily and recursively from bottom to top)—or, equivalently, does `r.` actually mean something like "regex accepting the empty string, except when it's the first element inside a parenthesized expression"?

Comment: @abarnert I'm not entirely sure... I just added one rule to the beginning that I missed, not sure if it answers your question(s) at all. Sorry

Comment: Plenty of examples involve prefix notation. For example, all of the boolean parsers handle `not` as a prefix operator; the Python literal parsers handle unary `+` and `-`; etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start attacking this by breaking up parenthesized vs. atomic expressions. Something like this BNF:

```
<expr> ::= "(" <paren-expr> ")"
         | <atomic-expr>

<exprs> ::= <expr>
          | <expr> <space> <exprs>

<atomic-expr> ::= <empty-expr> | <nothing-expr> | <char>

<paren-expr> ::= <union-expr> | <concat-expr> | <star-expr>

<union-expr> ::= "r|" <space> <exprs>

<star-expr> ::= "r*" <space> <expr>
```

Hopefully you can fill in the rest, and figure out how to translate that to an actual executable parser.